# Parsing JSON in Android using AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, json, asynchttpclient

I need to parse my JSON to my Android application, I’m getting an error:

> org.json.array cannot be converted to jsonobject

What I want to do is to take the json from my server and parse it into the textviews that i had made I’m using AsyncHttpClient, here is my code.

```
AsyncHttpClient client1 = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client1.get("http://mahmoudfa-001-site1.atempurl.com/appetizers.json",new

TextHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure ( int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable){

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess ( int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString){

        Log.i("a1", responseString);

        //testing if the server responding.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            JSONObject job = new JSONObject(responseString);
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(build);
            //String arrlen = Integer.toString(arr.length());
            JSONObject na = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray ingna = na.getJSONArray("unavailable");
            String[] ingr = new String[ingna.length()];
            for (int k = 0; k < ingna.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject abc = ingna.getJSONObject(k);
                ingr[k] = abc.getString("ingredient");
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject food = null;
                food = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = food.getString("name");
                String description = food.getString("description");
                String rating = food.getString("rating");
                String price = food.getString("price");
                String cooktime = food.getString("cooktime");
                JSONArray ingredients = food.getJSONArray("ingredients");
                String[] ing = new String[ingredients.length()];
                for (int k = 0; k < ingredients.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject ingd = ingredients.getJSONObject(k);
                    ing[k] = ingd.getString("ingredient");
                }


                for (int l = 0; l < ing.length; l++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < ingr.length; m++) {
                        if (ing[l].matches(ingr[m])) ;
                    }
                }


            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }

        try {
            JSONObject job = new JSONObject(responseString);
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(build);
            //String arrlen = Integer.toString(arr.length());
            JSONObject na = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray ingna = na.getJSONArray("unavailable");

            String[] ingr = new String[ingna.length()];
            for (int k = 0; k < ingna.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject abc = ingna.getJSONObject(k);
                ingr[k] = abc.getString("ingredient");
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject food = null;
                food = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String name1 = food.getString("name");

                if (name.equals(name1)) {
                    imageUrl[0] = imageUrl[0] + i;
                    nametext.setText("Name : " + name);
                    String description = food.getString("description");
                    detailstext.setText("Description : " + description);
                    String rating = food.getString("rating");
                    String price = food.getString("price");
                    price1 = Integer.parseInt(price);
                    pricetext.setText("Price : Rs. " + price);
                    ratingtext.setText("Rating : " + rating + " stars");
                    String cooktime = food.getString("cooktime");
                    cooktimetext.setText("Cooktime : " + cooktime);
                    JSONArray ingredients = food.getJSONArray("ingredients");
                    String[] ing = new String[ingredients.length()];
                    for (int k = 0; k < ingredients.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject ingd = ingredients.getJSONObject(k);
                        ing[k] = ingd.getString("ingredient");
                    }

                    String ingre = "Ingredients:";

                    for (int k = 0; k < ing.length; k++) {
                        if (k < (ing.length - 1))
                            ingre = ingre + " " + ing[k] + ",";
                        else
                            ingre = ingre + " " + ing[k];
                    }

                    ingredientstext.setText(ingre);
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Please I need help..
this is the JSON I am getting from my server:

[
    {
        "unavailable" :
                       [
                            {
                                "ingredient" : "Prawn"
                            },

```
                        {
                            "ingredient" : "Paneerygf"
                        },

                        {
                            "ingredient" : "Fish1"
                        }
                   ]
},  

{
    "name" : "Paneer Chilly",
    "description" : "Fried paneer pieces in chilly gravy",
    "rating" : "4",
    "price" : "100",
    "cooktime" : "20 mins",
    "ingredients" : [
                        {"ingredient":"Paneer"}
                    ]
},

{
    "name" : "Prawn Stuff Papad",
    "description" : "Papad stuffed with prawns and spices",
    "rating" : "3",
    "price" : "150",
    "cooktime" : "25 mins",
    "ingredients" : [
                        {"ingredient":"Prawn"}
                    ]
},

{
    "name" : "Fish Chilly",
    "description" : "Fired fish fillets with chilly gravy",
    "rating" : "3",
    "price" : "175",
    "cooktime" : "25 mins",
    "ingredients" : [
                        {"ingredient":"Fish"}
                    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Please show here what is your response `json`

Comment: the responseString is the file of json from here “http://mahmoudfa-001-site1.atempurl.com/appetizers.json"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: DefaultHttpClient  is duplicated, but I’m not using it. I’m using AsyncHttpClient, its newer and not duplicated.

Comment: Can you first see what the api returns, build a model of it and use Jackson or GSON for serializing/deserializing? It will make your code a lot cleaner and modular

Comment: there i edited it... please help ;-;

Answer (score 0):

The response returned from http://mahmoudfa-001-site1.atempurl.com/appetizers.json is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. You should parse it by `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString)`.

Comment: i tried to do that, thanks the error is not coming anymore, but i have a new problem now, its not parsing the json as well..